# google place autocomplete country restriction on change

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

i am using places autocomplete to find routes in map and is working fine.

I have a select box with 2 countries US and AU.When the select box change 
 i clear the autocomplete inputs and set the autocomplete 
componentRestrictions = {country: iso_country} with the new country value form select box.

When i first load the script the default country is US and the autocomplete is not suggesting any place from AU. (so far so good)

When i first load the script and directly change the country to AU the autocomplete is suggesting and places from US. (which in not what i want)

Here is my code

```
/*
 * When initialize
 * i apply autocomplete to the inputs
 */

if($("#from_place").length)
{
        apply_autocomplete($("#from_place")[0],default_iso_code);
    }
    if($("#to_place").length)
{
        apply_autocomplete($("#to_place")[0],default_iso_code);
}


/*
 * When the Select Box change 
 * i apply autocomplete to the inputs again with new iso_country
 */

$(document).on('change','#map_country_id',function() 
{
    var iso_country = $(this).val();

    //clear from/to
    $("#from_place").val('');
    $("#to_place").val('');

    //autocomplete from/to with new country
    if($("#from_place").length)
    {
        apply_autocomplete($("#from_place")[0],iso_country);
    }
    if($("#to_place").length)
    {
            apply_autocomplete($("#to_place")[0],iso_country);
        }
});

/*
 * the function that applies the autocomplete 
 * 
 */

function apply_autocomplete(input,iso_country)
{   
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: iso_country}
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);     
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue that you experience is because you try to create a new instance of Autocomplete on each change event of the select box. I would suggest not calling a `new` operator, but update the existing autocomplete instance properties using `setOptions()` method of Autocomplete class.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete

Have a look at the following example. I created two functions:

- `initAutocomplete()` that is executed after loading Maps JavaScript API and sets the initial state of autocomplete elements
- `updateAutocomplete(countryCode)` function that is called on each change event of select box

```js
var default_iso_code = 'US';
var autocomplete_from, autocomplete_to;

function initAutocomplete() {
  var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: default_iso_code}
  };
  if($("#from_place").length) {
    autocomplete_from = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#from_place")[0], options); 
  }
  if($("#to_place").length) {
    autocomplete_to = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#to_place")[0], options); 
  }

  $(document).on('change','#map_country_id',function() {
    var iso_country = $(this).val();

    //clear from/to
    $("#from_place").val('');
    $("#to_place").val('');

    updateAutocomplete(iso_country);
  });
}

function updateAutocomplete(countryCode) {
  var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: countryCode}
  };
  if (autocomplete_from) {
    autocomplete_from.setOptions(options);
  }
  if (autocomplete_to) {
    autocomplete_to.setOptions(options);
  }
}
```

```css
#from_place, #to_place {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}
#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="locationField">
      <select id="map_country_id">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input id="from_place" placeholder="From place" type="text"></input>
      <input id="to_place" placeholder="To place" type="text"></input> 
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!